# Icon-72.png : icon must be in PNG format

Tags: ios4

i created an app for iphone/ipad. i was taken app logo name Icon-72.png format. when i uploaded from application loader it displays an error message

> Icon-72.png : icon must be in PNG format

please help me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's icon properties problem. you can convert icon using the url http://iconverticons.com. It helps me. hope it will do for you.